# Python Version on Server - not changing

Tags: python, server

I'm new to running Python on servers, but I'm required to for one script and I just noticed that I was getting different output on my local vs. server machine.

**Locally, I run 3.6** and would like the server to run with that interpreter as well. Based off other questions, I tried to put `#!/usr/bin/env python3`
at the top of my code, but it doesn't seem to be working. For example, when I run this simple script on the server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
print(sys.version)
```

**The output is 2.7.5**. I'm sure I'm missing some obvious step, but not sure where it is. Again, I'm brand new to working with Python this way, so I'm not sure if I'm able to install it on the server (if that's the cause).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: run this command to check if python3 is installed "whereis python3"

Comment: nice - looks like it is there...I tried to install and permission was denied, so glad I don't have to go that route. This is what I got back ```python3: /usr/lib64/python3.3 /usr/lib64/python3.4 /usr/lib64/python3.0 /usr/lib64/python3.1 /usr/lib64/python3.2 /usr/local/bin/python3```

Comment: okay, then try #!/usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: Hm didn't work oddly. Saved file and re-ran, but got the same output as before. Weird...

Comment: how are you executing it ? if you did 'python filename.py' , it will execute with python2 compiler, you need to chmod it first and then run as ./filename.py or execute it as '/usr/local/bin/python3 filename.py'

Comment: Yeah - you guessed it was doing  'python filename.py'. It's actually going to be autorun, with 'python filename.py' (for school autograder) so I don't have the ability to change the actually commandline input. Is there another way within the file to change that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155681/discussion-between-user6142489-and-rupam).